# How to count number of matching object in image in Matlab

Tags: matlab, playing-cards, template-matching

I have a task where I should count numbers of suits(diamonds, clubs, ...) in a set of playing cards image. I have created a template sub-image from my original image for diamond for example, using imcrop in Matlab. I have also converted both Original or target Image in grayscale. 
I'm trying to find the match of the sub-image in the target image and counts the corresponding diamonds in the target image.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

I try to use normxcorr2 I got a plot where I can see the area with highest peak, but I don't have any ideas how to compute this.

Any suggestions of algorithms.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at method A) in  [Detect repetitive pixel patterns in an image and remove them using matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45041735/detect-repetitive-pixel-patterns-in-an-image-and-remove-them-using-matlab/45044648#45044648) *(Disclaimer: I'm the author)*. Delete the `rect` line and replace the variable `template` with your (BW) template. Skip the last 3 commands and instead just count how many peaks there are:

```
idx = bwmorph(idx,'shrink',inf);
numberOfObjects = sum(idx)
```

You obviously will have to adjust some values greatly to get a good result - pattern detection isn't trivial.

Comment: Hi, when u said "Skip the last 3 commands" its means I have to skip the dilation, the replication, and fillmissing function? I have tried the code it seems to perform well but, I'm not getting the output on workspace. I used "s= fprintf('\n total number of diamonds:%f' , num2str(numberOfDiamonds));" I got long loop of value. Any recommendations?

Comment: Skip everything *after* the `repmat` line. `s = fprintf()` just gets the number if bytes. If you want to display it in the console, `fprintf('total number of diamonds:%d \n' , numberOfDiamonds)` should do it. Else see the `fprintf` documentation for an example on how to write it to a file.